# Alamofire to download/upload multiple files in background

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My app needs to have a **Sync** feature. i.e A similar feature like **google photos**. User adds some images, tags , audio & bunch of other files.

Click on sync button & the files will be uploaded/ downloaded.

In android I used a service that helped achieving this functionality.

How can I achieve this functionality using **Alamofire networking library**.

This is what I tried.

```
class BackgroundDownload{
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("com.blabla.download.123"))

init(){
    for _ in 1...10{
        manager.request(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg")!)).response { (request, response, data, let error) in
            print(response)
            print(error)

        }
    }
}
```

}

It is a sample code. I call this from a ViewController.
The problems I am facing.

1.Where should I call my file downloading code so that **it continues to run in background**.

2. How to resume downloading if user shuts the app or for some reason the app restarts.

Comment: What have you tried? What issues did you encounter? Post a sample code reproducing the issue.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I tried. @redent84

Comment: @harsh_v , did you get any solution?

Comment: @Vats You can follow these links.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563154/swift-background-sync-manager/38611949#38611949 - This answer might help you with multiple download/uplaod with alamofire

https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started - for tasks in background

https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift - for operation queue

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 and Alamofire 4 and bellow** :
try this using Alamofire

```
class Networking {
    static let sharedInstance = Networking()
    public var sessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager // most of your web service clients will call through sessionManager
    public var backgroundSessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager // your web services you intend to keep running when the system backgrounds your app will use this
    private init() {
        self.sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        self.backgroundSessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.youApp.identifier.backgroundtransfer"))
    }
}
```

Use :
import Alamofire

```
let NetworkManager = Networking.sharedInstance.backgroundSessionManager

  NetworkManager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

       ****
       //do something when the request has finished
       ****

  }
```

Comment: This won't work with Alamofire 5, see https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/1d5411cdde887cb9c8d282239fa4a44d42bd5e9f

Comment: is there any progress? is this possible with Alamofire 5 now?

Comment: let add a full code of the example to a better understanding