# Swift Background Sync Manager

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make an Upload Manager Singleton that uploads multipart data every 10 minutes. The upload itself is clear but how can i make a class that uploads the data in this time interval in background?

Just to specify:

The data that I want to upload is a model that has an array of objects. Each of the objects has a flag and when this flag is set the object is ready for the upload. That whole "Sync-function" should be called once and repeat itself every 10 minutes, no matter on which ViewController I am. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code uses some external frameworks. It is based on recursion.

1. [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) // for networking

*The above framework is not important. I just used it to fasten the development process.

> Sync Manager

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


let SyncMangerIdentifier = "com.example.background.syncmanger"

class SyncManager: Alamofire.Manager{

    static let instance = SyncManager()
    private var pendingTasks = [SyncTask]() // SyncTask is a class with  3 variables [image,audio,[tags]] that are being uploading to server  
    private var request: Request?
    private var isSyncing = false


    private init(){
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier(SyncMangerIdentifier)
        configuration.allowsCellularAccess = Config.cellularAccess
        super.init(configuration: configuration)
    }

    // CALL THIS FUNCTION TO START THE SYNC
    // variable isSyncing guards multiple execution of syncManager  
    func start(){
        guard !isSyncing else {
            // WE ARE ALREADY SYNCING
            return
        }

        // CALL TO PREPARE FUNCTION TO EVALUATE WHETHER WE CAN SYNC OR NOT
        prepare()
    }


    /*
     initialize the syncItem variable with the first entry from SyncTask
     if we are stopping return
     if syncTask isEmpty stop
     if there are no items in first syncTask remove the task and restart the process.

     */
    private func prepare(){

        // I use a database query to store & retrieve pendingTasks

        guard !pendingTasks.isEmpty else{
            // todo no more data to sync
            isSyncing = false // syncing process ended

            // Notify app that your long running task has finished 
            (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.endBackgroundSyncTask()
            return 
        }

        isSyncing = true // we are in syncing process

        // Notify app that our long running task has begun
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.beginBackgroundRestoreTask()

        // Call function to start the first upload
        uploadFileOrData()
       }
    }


    /**
     upload the files & data from array recursively 
     */    
    private func uploadFileOrData(){
        var task = pendingTasks[0] 

        let imageUrl = task.imageUrl
        let audioUrl = task.audioUrl
        let tags = task.tags.reduce(""){ prev, next in
            if prev.isEmpty{
                return next.text
            }
            return "\(prev),\(next.text)"
        }

        let form : (MultipartFormData) -> () = { data  in

            if imageUrl.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil){
                data.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imageUrl, name: "image")
            }

            if audioUrl.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil){
                data.appendBodyPart(fileURL: audioUrl, name: "audio")
            }
            data.appendBodyPart(data: tags.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,allowLossyConversion: false)!, name: "tags")

        }

        upload(.POST, Api.fileUploadUrl, multipartFormData: form ,encodingCompletion: {

        // Call function to process the response
            self.processUploadFileResponse($0)
        })
    }

    private func processUploadFileResponse(result: Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult){
        switch result {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):

           // PERFORM ACTION ON SUCCESS

           // MOVE TO NEXT LOCATION
            self.moveToNextTask()

        case .Failure(_):
            // PERFORM ACTION ON FALIURE

            // MOVE TO NEXT LOCATION
            self.moveToNextTask()
        }
    }




   private func moveToNextTask(){
        // DELETE pendingTasks[0] & CALL prepare() function

        // If you want to repeat after every 10 MINUTE
        // Then wrap your function call 'prepare()' inside dispatch_after


        dispatch_after(
                    dispatch_time(
                        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                        Int64(10 * 60 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))  // 10 * 60 to convert seconds into minute 
                    ),
                    dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.prepare()
                })

            }
```

> AppDelegate class

```
// bind the alamofire backgroundCompletionHandler
func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //        NSLog("handle events for background: \(identifier)")
    if identifier == SyncMangerIdentifier{
        SyncManager.instance.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
}

// Identifier for long running background task for SyncManager class
var backgroundSyncTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

// Call this at the beginning of syncing
func beginBackgroundSyncTask() {

    backgroundRestoreTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({
        self.endBackgroundRestoreTask()
    })
}

// Call this when syncing process ends
func endBackgroundSyncTask() {

    guard backgroundSyncTask != nil else {
        return
    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundSyncTask!)
    self.backgroundSyncTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

> Note

*In order to continue request when your app enters background you may need to enable BackGroundFetchMode from app's Capabilities section*

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the method of upload to be called in all ViewControllers(VCs) One approach would be :-

```
extension UIViewController
{
   func uploadData(parameters) ->Bool
   {
   return true/false;
   }
}
```

Then in all ViewControllers(VCs) you can call uploadData method in viewDidLoad or in specific function like :-

```
if(self.uploadData(parameters))  // if true method is called i.e. new objects available to upload or 10mins have passed as per your requirement
{
}
```

Second Approach would be to define the NSTimer part which checks whether 10 mins have passed in AppDelegate and create a empty Swift file which does Upload and call the method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions within AppDelegate.

There are many ways to go about it but it depends on how flow needs to happen in your app.

**Note:-** Use 
NSURLSessionUploadTask  - > To upload and 
NSTimer -> To check whether 10 mins have passed

Comment: Thanks for your response! But i don't want to call the function in every ViewController. I want to call it once at the first ViewController and then call itself every 10 minutes

Comment: then you can do with second approach

Comment: is it for sync purpose, i think the approach would end up consuming a lot of user resources and bandwidth if it continues to upload every 10 mins.

Comment: I think this link might help :- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch--mobile-20520